# How to aggregate sum by a date range and join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a customer subscription table a, mostly with 1 year contract. The period starts at the 1st day of the month, and ends at the last day of the month.

```
,companyid,startdate,enddate
16216,10020659,2015-08-01,2016-07-31
23926,10020659,2016-08-01,2017-07-31
30078,10020659,2017-08-01,2018-07-31
```

there is table b to track the activities of customers:

```
,companyid,isomonthofyear,count1,count2,count3
6325,10020659,2015-06-01,348,346,2
23605,10020659,2015-07-01,509,499,10
465310,10020659,2015-08-01,561,543,18
473875,10020659,2015-09-01,467,453,14
661421,10020659,2015-10-01,528,518,10
515050,10020659,2015-11-01,586,578,8
508636,10020659,2015-12-01,520,507,13
728064,10020659,2016-01-01,602,599,3
728024,10020659,2016-02-01,604,596,8
532500,10020659,2016-03-01,967,958,9
528642,10020659,2016-04-01,725,710,15
496834,10020659,2016-05-01,811,800,11
496701,10020659,2016-06-01,677,661,16
496682,10020659,2016-07-01,694,676,18
465301,10020659,2016-08-01,870,858,12
```

I want to aggregate the sum of activities(count1-3) only for the subscription period, and join to table a:

```
,companyid,startdate,enddate,sum_count1,sum_count2, sum_count3
 10020659.   2015-08-01,2016-07-31      10 20 30
 10020659,   2016-08-01,2017-07-31      14 589 29
,10020659,2017-08-01,2018-07-31         20 40 30
```

Notice, there are non-subscription activities and different companies. I guess we can convert the enddate to first day of the month.

Comment: If possible can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly ensure that date like columns are of dtype datetime:

```
df1['startdate']=pd.to_datetime(df1['startdate'])
df1['enddate']=pd.to_datetime(df1['enddate'])
df2['isomonthofyear']=pd.to_datetime(df2['isomonthofyear'])
```

Finally:

```
out=df1.merge(df2,on='companyid',how='right')
#merging both df's on 'companyid' so to checking our criteria
m=out['isomonthofyear'].between(out['startdate'],out['enddate'])
#checking if it is under the subscription period or not
out=out[m].rename(columns={'counts':'count3'}).groupby('companyid').sum().add_prefix('sum_').reset_index()
#Filtering rows(selecting only those which are in subscription period) and then grouping them on companyid and performing sum
out=df1.merge(out,on='companyid',how='left')
#Finally merging the calculated sum with df1
```

output of `out`:

```
    companyid   startdate   enddate     sum_count1  sum_count2  sum_count3
0   10020659    2015-08-01  2016-07-31     8612         8457    155
1   10020659    2016-08-01  2017-07-31     8612         8457    155
2   10020659    2017-08-01  2018-07-31     8612         8457    155
```

Comment: thank you, I added the grooupby to  ['companyid', 'startdate'], and merge(out, on=['companyid', 'startdate'])